# Div based product list or table based?

Tags: html

Whats the difference in using a div based product list on my ecommerce site or tables. Is the div option better performance wise? Im trying to optimize my site and I am using tables at the moment to display my products.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using lists(ul/ol) for the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The choice shouldn't be between divs and tables. It is between semantic markup with CSS for presentation or presentational markup / markup with wrong semantics but desired presentational side effects.

Thinking about it in terms of divs or tables tends to lead down a road of divitus, and markup that is almost as bad as abusing tables for layout.

See [why not use tables for layout in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

If you just have a list of item names, use `div`s as it will improve performance.  If you have tabular data - data with many columns - `table`s are the way to go.

For a similar question, see here: [Actual table Vs. Div table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617895/actual-table-vs-div-table)

Answer (score -1):

It really depends. IMHO If you just want to display a grid of data, a table is likely the way to go. That being said, a div-based layout is easier to style and add/remove rows.