# side by size div to have same height and responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

using bootstrap, what I want is to have the left column to be the same height with left column. I can't set a fixed with since the content on left is dynamic. What do you think is the best solution?

demo http://daysof.me/interview/

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need to use JavaScript to accomplish this, as CSS is content agnostic. With JavaScript you can calculate the height of the left column, and then apply that same height to the right column.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible without the use of a script

Here is a working example : [Chatfield Drilling](http://chatfielddrilling.com/Chatfield%20V2/wfilter.php)

In the sideBar, click on one of the titles to see why overflow: auto; helps.

**BUT**

It has it's restrictions. This is a little setup I created and use a lot.

Con

- Left column must be relative, static, or your floats cleared
- overflow: auto; is strongly recommended
- uses absolute positioned elements
- can get tricky to maintain

The right sideBar will follow the height of it's brother mainBody and this is why I add `overflow: auto;` to the equation. When the content on that side is longer you can just scroll through the div.

The height of the parent is based on the left side and this is where you put the bulk of your info.

Just view this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/V66Je/3/) and watch as the sideBar grows with it's parent when you add more text.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="mainBody">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad similique scripserit vix, dictas graecis qui cu, an vis ubique aperiri. Duo in impetus maiorum, pro dolorem alienum liberavisse an. Vim veri inani conclusionemque eu. Omnesque consequat vix id, ut sit ferri illud. Cu cum elitr eirmod, vim dolorum sadipscing ne.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sideBar"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.mainBody {
    width: 60%;
    background: brown;
}

.sideBar {
    width: 35%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: tan;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: @Cam Thank you, it seems to work pretty well every time I have used it.

Comment: It seems to me there are too many restrictions for such a simple layout. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617895/actual-table-vs-div-table

Comment: Tables are for tabular data NOT structure. Maybe it is time to read up on this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html. The only reason tables were used for structure was due to the limitations in the 90's. It is no longer the 90's and you can accomplish more with less html markup then a table. Elements should be used the correct way not because it is "easier", later down the road when you have to edit 100 pages when you could have edited one class in your css file will make nothing easier about tables.