# What is the significance of using a <div> tag in JSP?

Tags: html, jsp

Why we use `<div>` tag if same things can be done in `<table>` tag?

Is it used to separate all the contents of the page like content, menu, header, footer?

Comment: Is Google down again?

Comment: divs are block line elements. They are often used as containers for CSS alignment and styling, and can provide a nice break. However, Robby is right. This is easily googleable and I'm not sure how JSP fits in here.

Comment: You should read more about *what* is HTML and then ask yourself the same thing about JSP (and *why* introducing a new view technology in your project). But don't go too fast or you'll end up asking this kind of question. Take your time :)

Answer (score 1):

Question in title:

> What is the significance of using a `<div>` tag in JSP?

[`<div>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp) is html. JSP is html (including css, javascript and other resources like images) + Java server side elements:

- Java code called [scriptlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaou.html) which [**should be avoided at all**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1065197)
- Expression language, that thing between `${}` and `#{}`
- Proper tags like [JSTL](https://jstl.java.net/).

The former provides static content while the latter provides dynamic content in the produced web page. You combine both to get a well formed fancy web page to show to your users.

---

Questions in body of the post:

> Why we use `<div>` tag if same things can be done in `<table>` tag?

No need to reinvent the wheel. It is answered here: [Actual table Vs. Div table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2617895/1065197)

> Is it used to separate all the contents of the page like content, menu, header, footer?

Since HTML 5 you use `<article>` (content), `<menuitem>` (menu), `<header>` (header), `<footer>` (footer) instead of lot of `<div>`s. Still, you can keep using `<div>` for these purposes. More info: [HTML5 New Elements](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_new_elements.asp)