# Group multiple consecutive row cells into one with CSS?

Tags: html, css

Ok, here's a graphic to explain what I'm talking about:

[image: This is what my current table looks like]

[image: This is what I'd like my table to look like]

The first table would be what my html currently produces and the second table is what I'd like it to produce.

```css
#animalTable{
    display: table;
 }

.animalRow{
    display: table-row;
 }

.animalCell{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 33%;
 }
```

```html
<div id="animalTable">
    <div class="animalRow">
        <div class="animalCell">Dog</div>
        <div class="animalCell">Milton</div>
        <div class="animalCell">1/2/1998</div>
    </div>
    ...
 </div>
```

What would be the best/easiest way to get my desired table? I know I could brute force it by creating sub-tables inside the main table but I was wondering if there was a better way?

Also, sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: can u please post ur css

Comment: @MandarSant Sorry, I can't believe I forgot. Adding it now.

Comment: heay please post u r full code so that i can get idea what u r getting

Comment: what you excepted first image or second image  ???

Comment: @Sumitpatel second image

Comment: using div ? and width :px or % ???

Comment: I think better you can use `<table>` for this. If you are OK with the `<table>` try this: 1) http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_td_rowspan 2) http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_span :)

Comment: I also suggest using HTML table with `rowspan` here. There is no replacement for `rowspan` in current CSS (in future, it would be possible with CSS Grid Layout, but it isn't supported yet in any shipped browser).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using `tables` instead of `div` for this specific case. Here is why you should [Use tables for what they are meant to and div's for what they are meant to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617895/actual-table-vs-div-table).

What you are looking for is called **Colspan** and **Rowspan**, both are HTML `td` and `th` attributes.

Example:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
    <th>Savings for holiday!</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td rowspan="2">$50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can read further on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score -3):

Simple, add different class or id selectors and in the css, remove all borders and re-add the ones you want to keep. Example,

```
div{
border: none;
border-top: solid 1px black;
border-left: solid 1px black;
}
```

Correct me if I am misunderstanding. Otherwise, if you have any questions don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: Also, if you are going to downvote, please give a reason. No one likes an anonymous downvoter.

Comment: Your suggested solution just removes the borders between cells, but doesn't actually merge cells with their content into one cell, as OP asked.

Comment: My downvote goes for the same reason as Ilya's. It is simply not a correct colution of the problem.

Comment: Then that means I misunderstood what the question was. Thank your response though.