# Colspan, rowspan and layout using divs

Tags: html, css, layout, html-table

Tables to be used for tabular data. Divs to be used for layout.
This is what I get out of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2617895/448078) thread.

```css
.table {
    display: table;
    padding: 5px;
}
.tr {
    display: table-row;
    padding: 5px;
}
.td {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 150px;
    border: #000000 solid 1px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="tr">
        <div class="td">Row 1,
            <br />Column 1</div>
        <div class="td">Row 1, Column 2</div>
        <div class="td" style="background:#888888;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
        <div class="td">Row 2,
            <br />Column 1</div>
        <div class="td" style="background:#888888;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But the first most 'layout feature' I'm looking for relates to table's `colspan`, `rowspan`.
How can I implement the same behavior using divs?

Comment: When I need a tabulated layout .. I use the [Bootstrp Grid Layout](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)  It allows for pretty flexible ability to have table-like functionality (including `colspan` and `rowspan` -ish functionality)

Comment: [CSS grids](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) are more powerful, flexible and less full of class name soup than Bootstrap's flexbox based approach.